# Inserir automaticamente em mysql ao ler código de barras

Tags: mysql

Estou a tentar criar um projeto interno para registo de tarefas dos colaboradores com leitura de código de barras.
Neste momento tenho um exemplo de código para ler o código e submeter na tabela da base de dados.

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Registo de Tarefas</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submeter(){
document.coder.submit()
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<?php if(isset($_POST['codigo']) && $_POST['codigo']!=''){
echo "<script>alert('".$_POST['codigo']."');</script>";
}
else
{
?>
<form name="coder" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="codigo" onfocus="if(this.value.length==10){submeter()}" maxlength="10" onchange="if(this.value.length==10){submeter()}"  onkeyup="if(this.value.length==10){submeter()}" onblur="if(this.value.length==10){submeter()}" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Agora pretendia fazer o `insert` de uma forma mais automática, onde o colaborador ao ler o código de barras com o scanner faça logo o `insert` automático na tabela da base de dados, sem ter campos em HTML e sem ter que se deslocar ao pc, apenas o scanner estar ligado em rede.

**Acrescentar informação à pergunta:**

Não estou a perguntar como se faz o `insert` e a conexão ao `mysql`. A questão que estou a colocar é como fazer o `insert` automático ao ler o código de barras sem formulário.

Exemplo:

Ao ler o código de barras com o scanner, o código ser inserido na base de dados logo automaticamente, sem ter que usar um formulário. O scanner estar ligado em rede, e ao escrever o código que lê, escrevê-lo diretamente na tabela da base de dados. Não sei se é possível fazer o que pretendo.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss  a pergunta que associou à minha pergunta como possível duplicada, é muito diferente do que estou a perguntar. Eu não pretendo encontrar a resposta como inserir e conectar ao mysql, pretendo fazer a comunicação direta entre o leitor de códigos de barras e o mysql, não sei se é possível

Comment: Bruno, então continuarei com a minha opinião de que é duplicada. Lá na resposta eu comento os conceitos que você precisa saber para passar um valor qualquer da sua página para o banco de dados - que é exatamente o problema que está enfrentando. Não existe mágica na programação. Leia lá todos os conceitos que precisará estudar e saberá como resolver o seu problema.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss estive a ler todo a sua resposta e fiquei com o conhecimento de vários conceitos que desconhecia, muito completa a informação. Mas fiquei com uma dúvida sobre o que pretendo. Pergunto, para que o servidor web execute o php  tem sempre de haver um formulário? Ou o servidor web onde executa o php pode interpretar a entrada de dados do leitor de código de barras sem formulário?

Comment: Bruno, se o leitor estiver conectado diretamente ao servidor web é possível fazer algo do gênero, sim. Se for conectado a outro computador, você precisará enviar a informação pela rede - mas aí depende da sua infraestrutura e dos requisitos do projeto, ficando bem amplo para discutir aqui. Através do formulário é uma das formas (possivelmente a mais simples).

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, os leitores vão estar conectados ao computador do servidor web, são dois leitores, mas ainda não consegui ver como o posso fazer.